# If I reference a medical textbook or website for hand drawing bones is that considered copyright infringement?

Tags: illustration, drawing, copyright

I can't quite figure this one out. I am not copying a custom piece of work, I am copying something that is available in nature, bones. I am also not tracing it, I am drawing by hand using them as a reference for accuracy. So, is that considered copyright infringement? Does it depend on how similar my drawings are to the ones I visually copied?

So if I look at a medical website or book and see a knee bone, then I draw one on paper or in a graphics editing tool by looking, with my eyes, at the referenced image, is that going to get me in trouble somehow?

I mean, surely I don't have to go find my own skeleton to draw from... right??

Answer (score 3):

This is dodging the intent of the question a bit, but you could use the original Gray's Anatomy illustrations sources [at Bartleby](http://www.bartleby.com/107/) and [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category%3aGray%27s_Anatomy_plates). They're from the 1918 edition and are generally regarded as being in the public domain (IANAL).

Comment: "generally regarded" sounds great... but for my purposes I'm going to need more certainty than that... for example, could I slice them up and use them in a web application, an app that is for sale, etc?

Comment: Cool, on Wikimedia the images I am looking at say "This image is in the public domain because its copyright has expired. This applies worldwide."!

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on the copyright license, medical drawings are treated equal to any other subject being drawn.

[Here](http://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/is-it-copyright-infringement-to-make-a-drawing-bas-453819.html) is a question about making drawings using photographs as a reference.

From a case ruling quoted on that site:

> "To prove infringement, a plaintiff with a valid copyright must
>   demonstrate that: (1) the defendant has actually copied the
>   plaintiff's work; and (2) the copying is illegal because a substantial
>   similarity exists between the defendant's work and the protectible
>   elements of plaintiff's"

An interpretation of this could be: the pose, shading, angle, etc are "protectible elements", while human anatomy *itself* isn't. (But we're not lawyers!)

If your drawings aren't too blatantly copied you're probably safe under fair use.

Comment: Oof. I always hate it when people don't quote the gist of a link they provide, and now I did it myself. Thanks for having my back. :)