# Is it a copyright violation to trace everyday objects and use them for commercial use?

Tags: copyright

Is tracing/vectorizing furniture (everything in my home) for commercial use in violation of copyright?

How can designers make arrows, buttons, tiles, etc. that maybe accidentally copied?
I have button ideas but I worry I maybe accidentally copy.

Comment: This sounds very similar to a recent question: [Is it plagiarism if my logo looks similar to an existing one?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/24979/8708)

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is: a) it depends and b) ask a lawyer. But it's more complicated than that. Furniture design has some intellectual property protection, but not in the same sense as copyright does. However, a particular pattern on a particular fabric on a particular piece of furniture may have copyright protection. That said, you could still take a photo of said piece, and you'd then own the copyright to the photo. Long story short, you're likely fine, but as always, it depends...

Comment: Just like there are multiple different styles for the same icons made by different designers, there are multiple styles of buttons.  You are certainly not in trouble with a button design.  If you're worried it isn't unique enough, rejoice - that would make you very unlikely to get sued since others probably have variations of the design (afterall, you can only copyright to a point... I don't think the ideas of buttons can be copyrighted, for example).  Honestly, I'm pretty sure that tracing your furniture for vector art will not be a problem as long as you do something to make it your own.

Comment: The [best guidance on these questions I've seen is](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/11108/3327) that to infringe, there has to be **substantial similarity** with **protectible elements** of the original. So in your case I'd imagine (not a lawyer) that it would need to be a) recognisable and b) of something distinctive or unique. Generic features (e.g. the shape of an average sofa): no problem. Distinctive features (e.g. a particular pattern, or distinctive chair design): a problem unless you use it as only *inspiration*, creating something that is not *"substantially similar"*.

Comment: Be aware there is **no such thing** as a "Change it by 10% or more and it's legal" factor.